# No puedo utilizar el modulo 'fs', en windows

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo un problema, intento utilizar el modulo 'fs' propio de NODEJS, pero me sale el error, de que no pudo encontrarse.

Lo que hice, antes de realizar el post.

1. Instale de manera manual, dado algunos post.

   npm install -g fs
2. Realize, lo siguiente.

npm cache clean

npm install

Dado esas opciones sigue me da el mismo error.

[image: Aqui una captura, del error que sale en la consola.]

Comment: ¿Cual es el error que te aparece?

Comment: Sale el error de que no pudo ser encontrado.

Comment: no tienes que instalar `fs` ya esta incorporado a node. Mustranos el script y que version de node usas. `const fs = require('fs');` deberia ser suficiente.

Comment: Mi versión de node: 6.10.3 y mi versión de npm : 3.10.10. Se que viene con el core de NODE, pero me da ese error cuando realizo como lo mencionas @Emanuel Ve const fs = require('fs')

Answer (score 1):

Instala node en global, el modulo fs esta incorporado en el core de node, no necesita instalacion aparte.

Comment: Muchas Gracias PacoTiger, encontré la razón del motivo por el que no funciona el fs. El asunto es el siguiente: El modulo fs de node que viene integrado, solo funciona cuando se trata el compilado de tu js como server, en mi caso lo estaba utilizando en modo browser, motivo por el que no podía encontrar dicho modulo.